# Can't query using cell reference from other functions in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to get an integer value from another cell, `A1`, into my Google Sheets query:

```
=QUERY(B:F; "select B where F > "& A1 &"limit 1")
```

I get this error:

> PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " "," ", "" at line 1, column 27. Was expecting one of:  "group" ...

`A1` contains a function `=B1+C1` and that returns an integer. Though this query works if `A1` is a hard-coded value like 100. I am not sure what is causing this error could be a parsing error or query error. Does anyone know how to fix it?

NOTES:

The referred cell, `A1`, has currency formatting in swedish krona(kr) that's *not* something custom. The regional settings are set to Sweden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when you set the *reference cell* inside an `Value(S13)`. It didn't work because of a **bug** in ***Google Sheets***. Did try the query in another sheet, without `Value(S13)` and it worked, that confirms the bug.

This is the workaround query:

```
 =QUERY(B:F; "select B where F > "& Value(S13) &"limit 1")
```

*The pseudo sheet for testing*

[image]

Comment: What is the formula / value on G2 and on the referred cells?

Comment: G2 consists of -> = E2 + F2, nothing fancy. The referred cells contains SUM(..), still nothing fancy.

Comment: Do you applied a custom number format? What's the regional setting of your spreadsheet?

Comment: It's currency, swedish krona(kr) and not something custom. The regional settings are set to Sweden.

Answer (score 1):

try it like this:

```
=QUERY(B:F; "select B where F > '"& A1 &"' limit 1"; 0)
```

or with `INDIRECT`:

```
=QUERY(B:F; "select B where F > '"& INDIRECT("A1") &"' limit 1"; 0)
```

Comment: This quotations are for strings `'"& A1 &"'`, right? Tried both of the examples you gave, didn't work.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug?

Comment: It worked when i was about to create an psudo sheet, i could post here. It's some kind of bug, have seen that Google Sheets sometimes is not following along as it should. When adding new functions, sometimes the others cells connected to it is not updated. It works fine after a refresh. It's not reliable. Should get Microsoft Excel instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing space before `limit` (it should be `" limit 1"` instad of `"limit 1"`)

Instead of

```
=QUERY(B:F; "select B where F > "& A1 &"limit 1")
```

use

```
=QUERY(B:F; "select B where F > "& A1 &" limit 1")
```

Explanation

If the of A1 is an integer like 100 the resulting argument is

```
select B where F > 100limit 1
```

but that isn't a syntax supported for Google Query Language

Comment: Sure it could be a parsing bug that occurs in obscure cases, but that isn't the case.  As you can see in my answer it works with or without the spacing, have tried both since you posted. Thanks for the clarification.